# Are protected members accessible in non-direct descendants?

Tags: c++

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access,

> protected members are accessible within the class and its methods and in its descendants

Do they mean *direct* descendants only, and not descendants of descendants, or do they mean *all* descendants?

e.g. If class C is a subclass of B, and B is a subclass of A which has a protected member, then B can obviously access it, but what about C?

Comment: The answer is yes: http://ideone.com/lWL71q (easily testable tbh)

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, so now I have to figure out why my code is giving me an error. Thanks.

Comment: @DmitriShuralyov "now I have to figure out why my code is giving me an error" You should have *started* with that, really :):):)

Comment: If the answer to my question was "direct descendants only", then that would explain why I'm getting this error. But since it's not, it has to be something else.

Comment: Ok, I think this is the error I'm getting: http://ideone.com/2t3VWO Wonder how to fix it (the easy way out is to make SomeProtectedMethod() public, but is there a way that doesn't require that?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Protected members are available to all descendants until/unless you reach a point that private inheritance was used. So, as long as your A, B, and C all use public inheritance (or protected inheritance, though that's rare enough to almost ignore), then yes, the most-derived can still used protected members from the most-base class (and if there were D, E, and F, the same would remain true).

Answer (score 3):

All descendants.

Also, you should just try it yourself sometimes, make a main.cpp somewhere and just try it. That's how you'll learn the most.

(Of course, I'm assuming here that you are using public derivation all the way, since you did not specify otherwise)

Good luck

Comment: I thought it was all descendants, but I'm getting an error that suggests otherwise, that's why I started doubting myself and and wanted to seek clarity in the C++ spec, but it was worded ambiguously.

Comment: Counterexample: `struct A{ void foo(){} }; struct B : private A{}; struct C : public B{}; C c; c.foo(); // oh oh...` (note that this example still holds if you use `protected: void foo() ...`)

Answer (score 1):

> Do they mean direct descendants only?

No - descendents of descendents, descendents of descendents of descendents, and so on, are also eligible. They all can access protected members of all their base classes, all the way up the chain of inheritance.

```
class A {
protected:
    int val;
public:
    A(int x) : val(x) {}
};

struct B : public A {
    B(int x) : A(x) {}
};

struct C : public B {
    C(int x) : B(x) {}
    void show() {
        cout << val << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c(123);
    c.show();
    return 0;
}
```

The above [compiles and prints `123`](http://ideone.com/HZLPKN).

Answer (score 1):

The protected methods are either protected or private in the first descendent (depending on how the descended inherited). From there on their status is determined as if they were that class's members per the inheritance rules.

Example:

```
class A{
   protected: int var;
}

class B : private A{
}

class C : protected A{
}

class D : public A{
}
```

In `C` and `D` variable `var` is protected, in `B` its private and cannot be seen by further descendents.